# Draw not straight timeline with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drawing

I'm starting with flutter and I need to draw something close to a timeline (its not really one, it just looks like it). The final result must be this:

[image]

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.